# Accessing java variable from javascript in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

i am relatively new to spring mvc.what i am trying to do is pass a variable as model attribute and try and access it on page load with javascript on my JSP page.
my java code is as follows

```
   model.addAttribute("leagueCode",leagueCode);
    model.addAttribute("league","new");
    return "redirect:/Dashboard";
```

and  on jsp side i am trying to access it by following

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function myFunction() { var leagueCode=${leagueCode}; alert(leagueCode); } </script> </head> <body onload="myFunction()">
```

---

but i am getting the value  as blank. is this the right way i am following or is there any other way this has to be done? please help

Comment: this way it's not possible. You need to bind the model value in DOM element with proper Id or class and get that value in script using that ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSP page you can set the values as javascript variables by adding a script tag in the `<head>` with the assignment inside as a json object for example:

```
<script>
var myServerSideVars = {
    "aServerSideVarName" : "<here you set the value with el/jslt/scriptlet>",
    "anotherServerSideVarName" : "<here you set the value with el/jslt/scriptlet>" 
};
</script>
```

**EDIT I**

Example using EL (Expression Language) but the same could be done with scriptlets if you are using that (`<% %>`):

Lets say in your Servlet you put a Car instance in the request before forwarding to the JSP page.

The car:

```
public class Car{
    protected String brand;
    protected String year;

    //getters and setters for the two properties.
}
```

In the Servlet you put it into the request:

```
Car car = new Car();
car.setBrand("BMW");
car.setYear("2017");
request.setAttribute("carInRequest", car);
```

In the JSP you set it to a Json Object accessible from javascript. Before closing the body tag I put a simple example of how the var can be accessed from javascript. I haven't run it so it may have some typo or error to correct:

```
<%@taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

    <html>
       <head><title>System.out.println</title>
          <script>
              var aCar= {
                     "brand" : "${requestScope.carInRequest.brand}",
                     "year"  : "${requestScope.carInRequest.year}"
              };
          </script>
       </head>

       <body>
          <h2>Brand: <span id="brandPlaceHolder"></span></h2>
          <h2>Year: <span id="yearPlaceHolder"></span></h2>

       </body>
       <script>
           var brandSpan = document.findElementById("brandPlaceHolder");
           brandSpan.html = aCar.brand;
           var yearSpan = document.findElementById("yearPlaceHolder");
           brandSpan.html = aCar.year;
       </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: sir can u please elaborate on this.i am having difficulties in understanding this

Comment: I have added a trivial example.